# Question to "How to Design Programs", I Fixed-Size Data, 1.7, Exercise 9

Tags: racket

The exercise is the following:
"Exercise 9. Add the following line to the definitions area of DrRacket:
(define in …)
Then create an expression that converts the value of in to a positive number. For a String, it determines how long the String is; for an Image, it uses the area; for a Number, it decrements the number by 1, unless it is already 0 or negative; for #true it uses 10 and for #false 20."

My problem is only to understand the last part of it with the number. I don't exactly understand what happens with it. As far as I understand, I define in with a number and have then to make an if-statement. It should subtract the number by 1, with isn't or 0. However it says also then if true I should use 10 and if false 20, I don't really get what they mean with I should use 10 or 20?

So far I just made a code which does, that if a number is 0 or negative, that it should leave the number as it is, if it larger than 0, then it subtracts 1.

```
(define in 23)
(if (<= in 0) in (- in 1))
```

Answer (score 1):

It said that if `in` itself evaluates to `#true`, then the expression should evaluate to `10`. This is different from "if the conditional (in `if`) evaluates to `#true`, then the expression should evaluate to `10`", which, as I understand, is your current (but incorrect) interpretation.

For instance:

```
(define in #true)
<your expression>
```

`<your expression>` should evaluate to `10`

```
(define in #false)
<your expression>
```

`<your expression>` should evaluate to `20`

```
(define in 23)
<your expression>
```

`<your expression>` should evaluate to `22` (because `in` is a Number that is neither 0 nor negative).

```
(define in "hello")
<your expression>
```

`<your expression>` should evaluate to `5` (the length of `"hello"`).

And so on.

Also note that when `in` evaluates to a non-positive number, the exercise doesn't describe what `<your expression>` should evaluate to exactly, but it does say that it should be positive. Your current code ("leave the number as it is") is wrong because the result would not be positive.

Make sure you read section 1.7 in detail. You will need to use `boolean?`, `number?`, `string?`, `image?`, `string-length`, and more. You might also find `cond` (introduced in "Prologue: How to Program") handier to use than a bunch of `if`s.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your answer. I think I understand it more.

So far I did this.

---

For string

```
(define in "kitty")
(if (string? in) (string-length in) in)
```

Result here was 5

---

For an image (Where I wrote picture, there was a picture and not a text.)
(define in picture .)

```
(if (image? in) (* (image-width in) (image-height in)) in)
```

Result here was 8775

---

For the number

```
(define in 23)
(if (<= in 0) in (- in 1))
```

Result was 22.

---

For the boolean (However this one is not working it says: "=: expects a number as 1st argument, given #true")

```
(define in #true)
(if (= in #true) 10 20)
```

(I'm not really sure now, how I need to change this part that it works.)

---

I think beside of the boolean part, it looks fine so far. I tried figure out how to do the boolean one, but I'm really not sure on how to rewrite it.

For cond I really didn't try out much there yet. I think I need to reread chapters before.

Comment: For one thing, `<your expression>` should be the same across all inputs. That is, you should have one `<your expression>` that works whether the input is a boolean, a string, a number, an image, etc.